# AngularJS, updating scope between controllers and html

Tags: angularjs

I have built a service that is keeping track of the id of a record within a telerik grid.  On selecting a row in the grid the service successfully fires and updates the data.  My problem is that the controller that handles my navigation doesn't see the change and I don't fully understand how to accomplish this as I am fairly new to angularjs and front end development.

```js
app
  .controller('FindCardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'NavService', function($scope, $http, NavService) {


    $http.get('../../sampleData/cardData.json').then(function(data) {

      var cardObj = data.data.cards;


      var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          data: cardObj.card,
        },
        columns: [{
            hidden: true,
            field: "id"
          },
          {
            field: "card_number",
            title: "Card Number"
          },
          {
            field: "name_on_card",
            title: "Name On Card"
          },
          {
            field: "billing_zip_code",
            title: "Billing Zip Code"
          },
          {
            field: "balance",
            title: "Balance"
          }
        ],
        noRecords: true,
        editable: false,
        sortable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        selectable: "row",
        change: function(e) {
          var selectedRows = this.select();

          var selectedDataItems = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
            selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
          }

          NavService.setCardId(selectedDataItems[0].id);

        },
        pageable: {
          pageSize: 20,
          previousNext: true,
          input: true,
          buttonCount: 5,
          pageSizes: [20, 30, 40, "all"],
          info: true,
          messages: {
            page: "Enter page"
          }
        },
        filterable: {
          mode: "menu",
          ignoreCase: true,
          operators: {
            string: {
              eq: "Equal to",
              contains: "Contains",
              startswith: "Begins with"
            },
            date: {
              eq: "Equal to",
              gt: "After",
              lt: "Before",
              eq: "Equals",
              gte: "After or equal to",
              lte: "Before or equal to"
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }]);
```

```js
'use strict';


app
  .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'NavService', function($scope, $http, NavService) {
    $scope.oneAtATime = false;

    //$http.get('../../sampleData/cardData.json').then(function (data) {
    //var card = getObjects(data, "id", NavService.cardData.cardId);

    //  });
    $scope.$on('card-selected', function(event, NavService) {
      console.log(NavService.cardData.cardId);
    });
    //  console.log(NavService.cardData.cardId);
    //$scope.cardId = NavService.cardData.cardId;

    $scope.status = {
      isFirstOpen: true
    };
  }]);



function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
      objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
    } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
      objects.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}
```

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name backOfficeApp
 * @description
 * # backOfficeApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */

/*jshint -W079 */

var app = angular
  .module('backOfficeApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngMessages',
    'picardy.fontawesome',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.utils',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'angular-momentjs',
    'kendo.directives',
    'FBAngular',
    'lazyModel',
    'angularBootstrapNavTree',
    'angularFileUpload',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.select',
    'ui.tree',
    'ui.calendar',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'ngMaterial',
    'localytics.directives',
    'ipsum',
    'angular-intro',
    'dragularModule'
  ])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {

      event.targetScope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function() {

        angular.element('html, body, #content').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 200);

        setTimeout(function() {
          angular.element('#wrap').css('visibility', 'visible');

          if (!angular.element('.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
            angular.element('.dropdown').find('>ul').slideUp();
          }
        }, 200);
      });
      $rootScope.containerClass = toState.containerClass;
    });
  }])

  .config(['uiSelectConfig', function(uiSelectConfig) {
    uiSelectConfig.theme = 'bootstrap';
  }])

  //angular-language
  .config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: 'languages/',
      suffix: '.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
  }])
  .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('NavService', function($q) {
      var dataHolder = {};
      //It's important that you use an object or an array here a string or other
      //primitive type can't be updated with angular.copy and changes to those
      //primitives can't be watched.
      dataHolder.cardData = {
        "cardId": '0'
      };

      dataHolder.setCardId = function(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var cardId = id;
        angular.copy(cardId, dataHolder.cardData);

        deferred.resolve(dataHolder.cardData);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
      return dataHolder;
    })

  }])
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrap" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtTime" slimscroll="{height: '100%'}">
    <div uib-accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen" class="panel-default">

      <ul id="navigation" nav-collapse ripple>
        <li ui-sref-active="active">
          <a ui-sref="client.dashboard">
            <fa name="dashboard"></fa> <span>{{ 'Menu.DASHBOARD'| translate }}</span></a>
        </li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{'open':$state.includes('client.order')}">
          <a ui-sref="client.order">
            <fa name="shopping-cart"></fa> <span>{{ 'Menu.ORDER_MANAGEMENT' | translate }}</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li ui-sref-active="active">
              <a ui-sref="client.order_management.new">
                <fa name="caret-right"></fa> {{ 'Menu.NEW_ORDER' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active">
              <a ui-sref="client.order_management.history">
                <fa name="caret-right"></fa> {{ 'Menu.HISTORY' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active">
              <a ui-sref="client.order_management.cancel">
                <fa name="caret-right"></fa> {{ 'Menu.CANCEL' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{'open':$state.includes('client.card')}">
          <a ui-sref="client.card">
            <fa name="credit-card"></fa> <span>{{ 'Menu.CARD_MANAGEMENT' | translate }}</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li ui-sref-active="active">
              <a ui-sref="client.card_management.find">
                <fa name="search"></fa> {{ 'Menu.FIND_CARD' | translate }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul ng-if="cardId > 0">
            <li ui-sref-active="active">
              <a ui-sref="client.card_management.summary({cardId: cardId})">
                <fa name="caret-right"></fa> {{ 'Menu.SUMMARY'| translate }} </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: ignore the event in the NavCtrl, that was me experimenting trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event system in Angular to notify other controllers that they need to update their values:

```
app.service('MyService', function($rootScope) {
  var MyService = this;
  var item;
  MyService.setItem = function(value) {
    /*-- code to set item --*/

    // notify other controllers
    $rootScope.$broadcast('item-changed');

  };

  MyService.getItem = function() {
    // api call to get item
    // or get current item value from variable
  };

});


app.controller('MyOtherController', function($scope, MyService) {

  $scope.$on('item-changed', function() {
    MyService.getItem().then(function(result) {
      $scope.item = result;
    });
  });

});
```

In your NavCtrl, you are most of the way there, you just need to set the scope variable to the new `cardId` in your event listener:

```
  .controller('NavCtrl', [
     '$scope', '$http', 'NavService', 
     function($scope, $http, NavService) {
       //...
       $scope.$on('card-selected', function(event, NavService) {
         console.log(NavService.cardData.cardId);
         $scope.cardId = NavService.cardData.cardId;
       });
       //...
  }]);
```

You can't inject `$scope` into a service, but you can inject `$rootScope`. Broadcasting an event on `$rootScope` with send it to all scopes. Any scope that is listening for it will be able to respond to it.

Comment: so how does the html know about the change in the scope variable?  I can't get the UL to appear based on the ng-if condition.

Comment: Are you new to AngularJS? The view and scope relationship is the fundamental feature of AngularJS. Read about the digest loop to understand how the template is updated with changes to the `$scope`